# HBase co-processor: checkAndPut causing <Timed out on getting lock for row>

Tags: hbase

HBase version: 0.94.15-cdh4.7.0

I have a very simple setup:

- table **ttt** with data
- table **counters** with a counter (increment field)
- **prePut** corpocessor for the **ttt** table

When a row is being inserted/updated in the **ttt**, the coprocessor checks whether a value is present in the column **d:k** for the same row.
Should there be no value, coprocessor increments the counter in **counters** table and assigns it to the **d:k** column via **checkAndPut** method.

Code is as following:

```
@Override
public void prePut(final ObserverContext<RegionCoprocessorEnvironment> observerContext,
                   final Put put, final WALEdit edit, final boolean writeToWAL) throws IOException  {
    HTable tableCounters = null;
    HTable tableTarget = null;
    try {
        Get existingEdwGet = new Get(put.getRow());
        existingEdwGet.addColumn("d".getBytes(), "k".getBytes());
        tableTarget = new HTable(
                this.configuration,
                observerContext.getEnvironment().getRegion().getTableDesc().getName());

        if (!tableTarget.exists(existingEdwGet)) {
            // increment the counter
            tableCounters = new HTable(this.configuration, "counters");
            long newEdwKey = tableCounters.incrementColumnValue("static_row".getBytes(), "counters".getBytes(), "k".getBytes(), 1);

            Put keySetter = new Put(put.getRow());
            keySetter.add("d".getBytes(), "k".getBytes(), Bytes.toBytes(newEdwKey));
            tableTarget.checkAndPut(put.getRow(), "d".getBytes(), "k".getBytes(), null, keySetter);
        }
    } finally {
        releaseCloseable(tableTarget);
        releaseCloseable(tableCounters);
    }
}
```

Utilitarian functions/variables:

- **releaseClosable** - simple `.close()` with `try/catch`
- **this.configuration** - Hadoop Configuration obtained during coprocessor start

While executing simple PUT from the `hbase shell`:

```
for i in 0..10 do
    put 'ttt', "hrow-#{i}" , 'd:column', 'value'
end
```

the region reports a dead-lock:

```
2015-07-02 23:58:30,297 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer (IPC Server handler 43 on 60020): 
java.io.IOException: Timed out on getting lock for row=hrow-1
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.internalObtainRowLock(HRegion.java:3588)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.getLock(HRegion.java:3678)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.getLock(HRegion.java:3662)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.checkAndMutate(HRegion.java:2723)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.checkAndMutate(HRegionServer.java:2307)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.checkAndPut(HRegionServer.java:2345)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor31.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Server.call(WritableRpcEngine.java:354)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseServer$Handler.run(HBaseServer.java:1434)
```

Questions:

- are **checkAndPut** allowed to be executed from the **prePut** coprocessor?
- what else could be done to guarantee that in the concurrent environment, where multiple concurrent workers could be writing to the same **ttt** row, **d:k** value is assigned only once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual issue was an infinite loop, caused by **prePut** coprocessor calling a **.put** or **.checkAndPut** which was calling **prePut** coprocessor in its turn.

To break the loop, I have implemented following approach:

1. add a *marker* to the **put** being created
2. at the top of the coprocessor - check if the *marker* is present. If **yes** then remove the *marker* and skip the coprocessor. If **no** then this is a new request, not initiated earlier by this coprocessor; thus - continue with the flow

.

```
public static final byte[] DIM_FAMILY = "d".getBytes();
public static final byte[] COLUMN_KEY = "k".getBytes();
public static final byte[] COLUMN_MARKER = "marker".getBytes();
public static final byte[] VALUE_MARKER = "+".getBytes();

public static final TableName TABLE_COUNTERS = TableName.valueOf("counters");
public static final byte[] COUNTER_FAMILY = "c".getBytes();
public static final byte[] COUNTER_ROWKEY = "rowkey_counter".getBytes();
public static final byte[] COUNTER_KEY = "key_counter".getBytes();


public void prePut(final ObserverContext<RegionCoprocessorEnvironment> observerContext,
                   final Put put, final WALEdit edit, final Durability durability) throws IOException {
    if (put.has(DIM_FAMILY, COLUMN_MARKER)) {
        removeColumnMutations(put, COLUMN_MARKER);
        return;  // return from the coprocessor; otherwise an infinite loop will occur
    }

    HRegion region = observerContext.getEnvironment().getRegion();
    Table tableCounters = null;
    Connection connectionCounters = null;
    try {
        // check whether the key column for the row is empty
        Get existingEdwGet = new Get(put.getRow());
        existingEdwGet.addColumn(DIM_FAMILY, COLUMN_KEY);
        List<Cell> existingEdwCells = region.get(existingEdwGet, false);

        // check if key value is empty.
        // if so - assign one immediately
        if (existingEdwCells.isEmpty()) {
            // increment the key_counter
            connectionCounters = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(configuration);
            tableCounters = connectionCounters.getTable(TABLE_COUNTERS);
            long newEdwKey = tableCounters.incrementColumnValue(COUNTER_ROWKEY, COUNTER_FAMILY, COUNTER_KEY, 1);

            // form PUT with the new key value and a marker, showing that this insert should not be discarded
            Put keySetter = new Put(put.getRow());
            keySetter.addColumn(DIM_FAMILY, COLUMN_KEY, Bytes.toBytes(newEdwKey));
            keySetter.addColumn(DIM_FAMILY, COLUMN_MARKER, VALUE_MARKER);

            // consider checkAndPut return value, and increment Sequence Hole Number if needed
            boolean isNew = region.checkAndMutate(keySetter.getRow(), DIM_FAMILY, COLUMN_KEY,
                    CompareFilter.CompareOp.EQUAL, new BinaryComparator(null), keySetter, true);
        }
    } finally {
        releaseCloseable(tableCounters);
        releaseCloseable(connectionCounters);
    }
}
```

NOTES:

- Above coprocessor fits HBase 1.0 SDK
- Instead of opening connection to the underlying region, a HBase Region instance is used from the **RegionCoprocessorEnvironment** context
- utilitarian method **removeColumnMutations** can be omitted, and its only purpose it removing *marker* from the **PUT**